# Maximo cannot deliever message to endpoint

Tags: interaction, maximo

I've created an interaction in maximo 7.6 and when I try to run it, I get this error message:

> BMXAA1481E - Cannot deliver the message to the endpoint. Internal
>   Error

I've tried fixing it, but nothing works, does anyone how to fix this or even why does it pop up?

Comment: please describe your Maximo configuration steps and use the logging application to get more details on the error.

Comment: this may help: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/B-Fool/entry/maximo_interactions41?lang=en